# How can I locate tooltip <a href>tooltip</a> values inside the table using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

from this side https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China

I need the values of tables at the right side.
How can I get this?

I stored the header values and trying to match the table header and retrieve the column values but showing error.

```
List<String> search=new ArrayList<String>();
                 search.add("President");
                 search.add("Capital");
                 search.add("Dialing code");
                 search.add("Currency");
                 search.add("Population");
                 search.add("Official script");                 
                        for(int ii=0;ii<search.size();ii++) {
                            System.out.print("VALUE in search list ; "+search.get(ii));
                             for(int i=1;i<43;i++) {

                              String ss=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mw-content-text\"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr["+i+"]/th[1]")).getText();
                             System.out.println(" VALUE in ss ; "+ss+" tr["+i+"]");
                            if(ss.toLowerCase().contains(search.get(ii).toLowerCase())) {
                            System.out.println("value matched");
                            //WebElement web= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mw-content-text\"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td/a"));
                            //String title=web.getAttribute("title");
                            //System.out.println(title);
                            break;
                        }
                 }

            }
```

i need to get the href tooltip values of each column like President=Xi jinping,Capital=Beijing,official script=simplified chinese etc.But showing error .`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/th[1]"}`

Answer (score 0):

If you see the xpath what you are using and the HTML code for the same page what you have given, the first row(tr) of the table is having table header (th) and from the second row onwards, we have table data (td), but not th. That is the reason, you are getting text for 1st index and getting NoSuchElementException from the 2nd index onwards. You can change your xpath in such way to handle where ever table header is there and where table data is there. That will help you to fetch the data.

This xpath (//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr) gives 55 matching elements. If you apply //*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[1], it will match with first element and this element have 'th'. i.e. (//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/th[1]) will work. But for the 2nd index (//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]), we have td instead of th. There is a problem.

You can change your xptah based on above explanation (I have reviewed HTML for the same and observed some are having th and some are with td. In those cases, fetching all elements data with same xpath is not at all possible. The only possible way is to write the xpath individually or segregate all th's and td's and run the loop with if condition).